# task scheduling of NVIDIA GPU

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I have some doubt about the task scheduling of nvidia GPU.

(1)  If a warp of threads in a block(CTA) have finished but there remains other warps running, will this warp wait the others to finish? In other words, all threads in a block(CTA) release their resource when all threads are all finished, is it ok? I think this point should be right,since threads in a block share the shared memory and other resource, these resource allocated in a CTA size manager.

(2)  If all threads in a block(CTA) hang-up for some long latency such as global memory access? will a new CTA threads occupy the resource which method like CPU？ In other words, if a block(CTA) has been dispatched to a SM(Streaming Processors), if it will take up the resource until it has finished?

I would be appreciate if someone recommend me some book or articles about the architecture of GPU.Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The Compute Work Distributor will schedule a thread block (CTA) on a SM only if the SM has sufficient resources for the thread block (shared memory, warps, registers, barriers, ...). Thread block level resources such shared memory are allocated. The allocate creates sufficient warps for all threads in the thread block. The resource manager allocates warps round robin to the SM sub-partitions. Each SM subpartition contains a warp scheduler, register file, and execution units. Once a warp is allocated to a subpartition it will remain on the subpartition until it completes or is pre-empted by a context switch (Pascal architecture). On context switch restore the warp will be restored to the same SM same warp-id.

When all threads in warp have completed the warp scheduler waits for all outstanding instructions issued by the warp to complete and then the resource manager releases the warp level resources which include warp-id and register file.

When all warps in a thread block complete then block level resources are released and the SM notifies the Compute Work Distributor that the block has completed.

Once a warp is allocated to a subpartition and all resources are allocated the warp is considered active meaning that the warp scheduler is actively tracking the state of the warp. On each cycle the warp scheduler determine which active warps are stalled and which are eligible to issue an instruction. The warp scheduler picks the highest priority eligible warp and issues 1-2 consecutive instructions from the warp. The rules for dual-issue are specific to each architecture. If a warp issues a memory load it can continue to executed independent instructions until it reaches a dependent instruction. The warp will then report stalled until the load completes. The same is true for dependent math instructions. The SM architecture is designed to hide both ALU and memory latency by switching per cycle between warps.

This answer does not use the term CUDA core as this introduces an incorrect mental model. CUDA cores are pipelined single precision floating point/integer execution units. The issue rate and dependency latency is specific to each architecture. Each SM subpartition and SM has other execution units including load/store units, double precision floating point units, half precision floating point units, branch units, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [this article](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/presentations/S3466-Programming-Guidelines-GPU-Architecture.pdf). It's somewhat outdated, but I think it is a good starting point. The article targets Kepler architecture, so the most recent one, Pascal, may have some discrepancies in their behavior.

Answers for your specific questions (based on the article):

**Q1. Do threads in a block release their resource only after all threads in the block finish running?**

Yes. A warp that finished running while other warps in the same block didn't still acquires its resources such as registers and shared memory.

**Q2. When every threads in a block all hang up, will it still occupy the resources? Or, does a new block of threads take over the resources?**

You are asking whether a block can be preempted. I've searched through web and got the answer from [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/736932/cuda-programming-and-performance/what-happen-to-shared-memory-on-block-preemption-/post/4205088/#4205088).

> On compute capabilities < 3.2 blocks are never preempted.
>   On compute capabilities 3.2+ the only two instances when blocks can be preempted are during device-side kernel launch (dynamic parallelism) or single-gpu debugging.

So blocks don't give up their resources when stalled by some global memory access. Rather than expecting the stalled warps to be preempted, you should design your CUDA code so that there are plenty of warps resident in an SM, waiting to be dispatched. In this case even when some warps are waiting global memory access to finish, schedulers can launch other threads, effectively hiding latencies.

Comment: Yes,multiple blocks can run concurrently in an SM.But when a block (among multiple concurrently blocks on a SM)threads all hang up, will it still occupy the resource?